# “…her wrinkled fingers quick at…“ is there a lost "are" between fingers and quick?

Tags: ellipsis, literature

> She poured again a measureful and a tilly. Old and secret she had entered from a morning world, maybe a messenger. She praised the goodness of the milk, pouring it out. Crouching by a patient cow at daybreak in the lush field, a witch on her toadstool, her wrinkled **fingers quick at** the squirting dugs. They lowed about her whom they knew, dewsilky cattle.

This is an excerpt from Joyce's book, *Ulysses*. I'm wondering whether Joyce is deliberately doing something wrong in grammar just as he is deliberately creating new words in that book?

Comment: I think you meant *her fingers **were** quick*… because the prose is written in the past simple tense.

Comment: yes, I forgot ....maybe prose need not be so grammatical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is definitely some nonstandard grammar in this passage. However, Joyce did not leave out anything in that phrase. It is what is sometimes called a nominative absolute (among several other terms), which typically involves a nominal phrase modified by an adjectival phrase. Here is an example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_absolute):

> **The dragon slain**, the knight took his rest.

In Joyce's passage, "her wrinkled fingers" is the nominal phrase and "quick at the squirting dugs" is the adjectival phrase.

Comment: thank you! now I read it again, it seems to me that Joyce wants to express in a poem style, or express the thoughts which flew in his (stephen's) mind then quickly but not in grammaticaly ,these two explanations seems make sense to me

Comment: The sentence is grammatical but there **is** a null copula, “her wrinkled fingers **were** quick at squirting the dugs”

Comment: @Mari-LouA if it lost a were, how could it be grammatical?

Comment: @William8964  a **null / zero copula** is when a sentence / phrase omits the auxiliary verb. "John [was] tall as a tree, strong as an ox, fought with all his might.”  It's less common in English, so I couldn't begin to tell you when you can omit the auxiliary (copula). However, there are some languages where the copula is not needed, and there are some English dialects which omit "be" almost entirely.